# Efficient way to load a large amount of data to a Vanilla JS frontend with a Flask-MySQL-SQLAlchemy Backend?

Tags: json, architecture

I have a flask-based web-server setup that inputs a lot of unique data points. While insertion into the DB is done asynchronously, Getting data out of it is the harder part. For each request, I am looking at an average of 250,000 rows of raw data that needs to be displayed in a graph format using plotly.js. Executing the raw query on the MySQL command line takes about 10 seconds to return the data.

However, since I am using SQLAlchemy as my ORM, there seems to be a significant overhead. The extracted data then needs to be dumped into a JSON format to be sent to the front-end to display.

I understand that this situation has a lot of variables that can be changed but I am asking this question after about a week of trying to find solutions to this problem. Is the solution to throw hardware at it?

TLDR: Large amount of data in Backend(Flask, SQLAlchemy, MySQL); Need to display it on the frontend after querying 250,000 records of data and converting it to JSON; Any good solutions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention the size of the data. The JSON object that is sent is about 22.6MB for 250,000 rows of SQL. The table this problem deals with has about 15 columns with Floats, Timestamps, VarChars and Integers. I'm willing to give any more information that can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that launching an Async process that does this in the background and hope that it works is a perfectly good solution.